# How to get word hierarchy (e.g., hypernyms, hyponyms) using wordnet in R

Tags: r, hierarchy, wordnet, hypernym

I want to use the wordnet package in R to get the word hierarchies like: "animal" is the hypernym of "cat", and "apple" is the hyponym of "fruit". But the code I can find from R wordnet help file is like below to identify antonyms:

```
install.packages("wordnet", dependencies=TRUE)
library(wordnet)
filter <- getTermFilter("ExactMatchFilter", "cold", TRUE)
terms <- getIndexTerms("ADJECTIVE", 5, filter)
synsets <- getSynsets(terms[[1]])
related <- getRelatedSynsets(synsets[[1]],"!")
sapply(related, getWord)
```

How can I use the R wordnet package to find hypernyms and hyponyms of a word?

Answer (score 1):

you can replace `"!"` (which is for antonyms) in

```
related <- getRelatedSynsets(synsets[[1]],"!")
```

with other symbols depending on what you need.

See this link: 
http://wordnet.princeton.edu/man/wnsearch.3WN.html#sect4

Hypernyms would be `"@"`

**Extension to original question:**

I just started using WordNet and I am looking for something similar.
For 'apple' I would like a hypernym tree giving me

- 'fruit'

  - 'food'

    - 'solid matter'

      - 'physical entity'

        - etc...

as can be seen when clicking on `inherited hypernyms` on WordNet online
http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn

However, the following commands

```
filter <- getTermFilter(type="ExactMatchFilter", word="apple", ignoreCase=TRUE)
terms <- getIndexTerms("NOUN", 15, filter)
synsets <- getSynsets(terms[[1]])
related <- getRelatedSynsets(synsets[[1]], "@")
sapply(related, getWord)
```

will only give me

```
[[1]]
[1] "edible fruit"

[[2]]
[1] "pome"        "false fruit"
```

hence failing to provide me with lower levels of hypernyms

The key to climbing the hypernym tree is to **use getRelatedSynsets( ) recursively**.

Continuing with the above example, extracting synsets from apple's synsets:

```
related_2 <- getRelatedSynsets(related[[1]], "@")
```

And collecting the corresponding words:

```
sapply(related_2, getWord)
```

will yield:

```
[[1]]
[1] "produce"         "green goods"     "green groceries" "garden truck"   

[[2]]
[1] "fruit"
```

And going on step further:

```
related_3 <- getRelatedSynsets(related2[[1]], "@")

sapply(related_3, getWord)
```

will result in:

```
[,1]        
[1,] "food"      
[2,] "solid food"
```